# V-for on 2 seperate object arrays

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to output 10 news from an array called stories. This array contains info regarding the story. fx title, text, URL

But I'm also trying to output data on the author from that story that is stored in another array called authors. This array contains, author id, author score etc.

How do I accomplish this in Vue.js using the `v-for` method.

This is what I got for now:

```
 created: function (){
    axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json')
    .then((response) => {
      let results = response.data.slice(0,10)
      results.forEach(id => {
        axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + id + '.json')
        .then((response) => {
          this.stories.push(response);
          let myAuthor = response.data.by;
              axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/' + myAuthor + '.json')
              .then((myAuthors) => {
                this.authors.push(myAuthors);
              })
            .catch((err) => {
              this.err = err;
              alert("Error fetching authors " + err);
            })
              
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.err = err;
        })
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.err = err;
    }); 

  },
```

and the HTML:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="storyContainer" v-for="story in sorted_stories" :key="story">
            <span class="score">{{ story.data.score }}</span>
            <h2>Karma: {{ story.data.karma }}</h2>

            <a href="{ path: '/story/' + story.data.id }">{{ story.data.title }}<span>{{ story.data.url }}</span></a><br/>
            <span class="meta">
            by {{ story.data.by }} | {{ story.data.time }} | Story ID: {{ story.data.id }}
            </span><br>
    </div>
    <div v-for="author in authors" :key="author">
    <h1>ID {{ author.data.id }}</h1>
    <h1>Karma {{ author.data.karma }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can create another v-for in authors v-for and filter stories for author:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      stories: [],
      authors: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    storiesForAuthor(id) { //  method to filter stories for author id
      return this.stories.filter(s => s.data.by === id)
    }
  },
  created: function (){
    axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json')
    .then((response) => {
      let results = response.data.slice(0,10)
      results.forEach(id => {
        axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/' + id + '.json')
        .then((response) => {
          this.stories.push(response);
          let myAuthor = response.data.by;
              axios.get('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/user/' + myAuthor + '.json')
              .then((myAuthors) => {
                this.authors.push(myAuthors);
              })
            .catch((err) => {
              this.err = err;
              alert("Error fetching authors " + err);
            })
              
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          this.err = err;
        })
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.err = err;
    }); 
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPh3uwgU5qEMipS/VOmRqynnMXGGSRv+72H/N260MQeXZIK4PG48401Bsby9Nq5P5fz7hy5UGNmC/W1Z51h2GQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="author in authors" :key="author.id">
      <h3>ID {{ author.data.id }}</h3>
      <h5>Karma {{ author.data.karma }}</h5>
                                           <!--  inner v-for for filtering stories -->
      <div class="storyContainer" v-for="story in storiesForAuthor(author.data.id)" :key="story.id">
        <span class="score">{{ story.data.score }}</span>
        <h2>Karma: {{ story.data.karma }}</h2>

        <a href="{ path: '/story/' + story.data.id }">{{ story.data.title }}<span>{{ story.data.url }}</span></a><br/>
        <span class="meta">
        by {{ story.data.by }} | {{ story.data.time }} | Story ID: {{ story.data.id }}
        </span><br>
      </div>
      <hr />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @nikola. Is there a way to call a computed method as well? In my original post I use ``sorted_stories`` to sort by score. But that's no longer possible when using the storiesForAuthor. 
Thank you

Comment: @zevex hey mate, it this solution I'm assuming that one author can have multiple stories, so you can sort authors and stories for author. If you have only one story per author you can switch loops, and use ordered stories as outer loop and authors as inner (so change storiesForAuthor method for similar but authorForStory, infact you don't  need inner loop then )

Comment: How would you go about it in the case? Because both methods are independent of each other. I tried to switch loops but it does not work. Both methods work separately but not together. Sorry, I'm completely new to Vue js and its methods syntax.

Would it be easier to implement it in the created hook?